# Is there an easy proof of $d \star S = s \cdot \epsilon$ for two forms S

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, general-relativity

In https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.08616.pdf eq. 3.51 the following identity is proposed to hold for two-form $S$ on a manifold with metric $g_{\mu \nu}$.

$d \star S = s \cdot \epsilon$,

where $d$ is the exterior derivative, $\star$ the Hodge star operator and $s^\mu = g^{\mu \nu} \nabla^\sigma S_{\nu \sigma} $ and $\epsilon$ is the volume form of the given manifold. Is there an easy proof for this identity? Trying to work it out in coordinates became a mess to me and I couldn't find an reference for this identity.

Comment: Physicists' notations and tendencies are clearly ruling that paper. I've never before seen $s\cdot \epsilon$ written for $\iota_s\epsilon$. Here's my suggestion: First establish the formula when $S$ is the wedge product of two basis $1$-forms from an orthonormal basis (maybe normal coordinates at $p$ will help to establish it at $p$). Then show that if the formula holds for such an $S$, then it holds for $fS$ for any scalar function $f$. Since both sides are $\Bbb R$-linear, we can then take sums with impunity, and we're done.